# why the Tier Price doesn't show?

Tags: magento

I using the default template for my site. and add a `Tier Price` to a product. set to the `Customer Group` but it doesn't show on the product page. why?

[image]

how to output the above

Answer (score 1):

Check the below points.

```
* Clear cache.
* Check re-indexing.
* The tire price should lesser then normal price.
* Check the code of product view page whether the code was removed?
```

I hope this will helps you.